# Is in.readInt() equal to (Integer) in.readValue(Integer.class.getClassLoader()) in Parcelable of Android?

Tags: android, parcelable

My class:

```
public class XXX implements Parcelable {
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private String content;

...
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeValue(this.id);
        dest.writeString(this.title);
        dest.writeString(this.content);

    }

    protected XXX(Parcel in) {
        this.id = (Integer) in.readValue(Integer.class.getClassLoader());

        this.title = in.readString();
        this.content = in.readString();

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<XXX> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<XXX>() {
        @Override
        public XXX createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new XXX(source);
        }

        @Override
        public XXX[] newArray(int size) {
            return new XXX[size];
        }
    };
```

There are two ways to get id from Parcel:

```
this.id = (Integer) in.readValue(Integer.class.getClassLoader());
```

and

```
id = in.readInt();
```

Which should I use? Or any one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function readInt is for int value. Integer class object is something more than int. Use the readValue for it.

You can also think if *id* field should be Integer or int can be sufficient.